# using a For loop in python3 to create a 3 columns x 10 rows table in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am using a For loop to give values to three variables distance, cty, ctry. Then I want to store the values in a table in sqlite3. Unfortunately the program stores only the first row of values of the For loop in the sqlite3 database:

```
14004   GOROKA  PAPUA NEW GUINEA
```

Code:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
import sqlite3

R = 6373.0

conn = sqlite3.connect('global_airports_sqlite.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ports')
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Ports ( Delta INTEGER, City TEXT, Country TEXT )''')
coords= 'SELECT lat_decimal, lon_decimal, city, country FROM airports ORDER   
BY id ASC LIMIT 10'
for cord in cur.execute(coords):
 lat2 = radians(cord[0])
 lon2 = radians(cord[1])
 cty = cord[2]
 ctry = cord[3]
 dlon = lon2 - lon1
 dlat = lat2 - lat1
 a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
 c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
 distance = int(R * c)
 cur.execute('INSERT INTO Ports (Delta, City, Country) VALUES (?,?,?)',
 (distance, cty, ctry))
 conn.commit()
```

How can I make it store all 10 values in my three columns: Delta, City, Country?

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure about `sqlite3` package, I am using `pymysql` personally; however, I think the flow should be the same;

Thus, I think before you start your for loop, probably you need to fetch your data first?

```
...
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ports')
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Ports ( Delta INTEGER, City TEXT, Country TEXT )''')
coords= 'SELECT lat_decimal, lon_decimal, city, country FROM airports ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10')
cur.execute(coords)
data = cur.fetchall()
for records in data:
  ...
```

Give it a try

Comment: I worked it a bit more and you are right! it is better to fetchall() from the table do my calculations with a loop and then use cur.executemany to store the new values into a new table Ports. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two different cursors, one for the `SELECT` query and another for the `INSERT`. When you do the first `INSERT` query, the cursor no longer holds the remaining results of the `SELECT` query, so the loop ends.

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
import sqlite3

R = 6373.0

conn = sqlite3.connect('global_airports_sqlite.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur2 = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ports')
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Ports ( Delta INTEGER, City TEXT, Country TEXT )''')
coords= 'SELECT lat_decimal, lon_decimal, city, country FROM airports ORDER   
BY id ASC LIMIT 10'
for cord in cur.execute(coords):
     lat2 = radians(cord[0])
     lon2 = radians(cord[1])
     cty = cord[2]
     ctry = cord[3]
     dlon = lon2 - lon1
     dlat = lat2 - lat1
     a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
     c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
     distance = int(R * c)
     cur2.execute('INSERT INTO Ports (Delta, City, Country) VALUES (?,?,?)',
     (distance, cty, ctry))
     conn.commit()
```

Comment: The top of our answer might suggest OP that he really needs two cursors, but storing the query rows result for use in the loop enables him to use just one, if he likes to do so, like suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @progmatico That's another way to do it, but it means all the results have to be stored in memory. Not a big deal for a small query like this, but could be an issue for larger queries.

Comment: I agree with you. Cursors exist for a reason :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!!! I will have to agree with CL its not working. Allow me to clarify that I am working with two tables one is the airports from which I take lat_decimal, lon_decimal and I calculate delta distance which I want to store in the newly created table under the name Ports. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I copied that formula from a MySQL answer, I didn't realize that SQLite doesn't have similar functions.